# How to implement webhook code in Shopify CLI created app

Tags: webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

As a beginner, I need some very basic js help here I guess. I created a custom shopify app using Shopify CLI out of my terminal. I now want to implement code in the created Shopify App template, to receive webhooks from my Shopify, and I don't know how to do this.
Should I create a "app.rb" file to put the code there, or a "app.jsx" file, and where?
Do I need to "import" or "export" in order to connect my new webhook code to the rest of the App, and how? Just some basic advice, what to read, which tutorials to check, would be already awesome. The code I want to implement looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'sinatra'
require 'shopify_api'
require 'active_support/security_utils'

# The Shopify app's API secret key, viewable from the Partner Dashboard. In a production environment, set the API secret key as an environment variable to prevent exposing it in code.
API_SECRET_KEY = '******************'

helpers do
  # Compare the computed HMAC digest based on the API secret key and the request contents to the reported HMAC in the headers
  def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header)
    calculated_hmac = Base64.strict_encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', API_SECRET_KEY, data))
    ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(calculated_hmac, hmac_header)
  end
end

# Respond to HTTP POST requests sent to this web service
post '/webook/product_update' do
  request.body.rewind
  data = request.body.read
  verified = verify_webhook(data, env["HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256"])
  
  halt 401 unless verified
  # puts "Webhook verified: #{verified}" 
  # Process webhook payload
  # ...
end
```

Maybe it helps to show my file structure (with open "web" folder):
[image: File structure of Shopify Custum App]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to register PRODUCTS_CREATE and PRODUCTS_UPDATE but not CHECKOUTS_CREATE, If it helps.

```
import { DeliveryMethod } from "@shopify/shopify-api";

export default {
  PRODUCTS_UPDATE: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("PRODUCTS_UPDATE", payload);
      console.log("env: ", process.env);
    },
  },
  PRODUCTS_CREATE: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      console.log("--- Product create ---");
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(payload);
      console.log(
        `--- /Product create - Callback URL: https://${shop}${webhookId} ---`
      );
    },
  },
  CHECKOUTS_CREATE: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      const checkoutId = payload.id;
      console.log(`--- Checkout created ${checkoutId} ---`);
    },
  },
  CHECKOUTS_UPDATE: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      console.log("Cart webhook hit");
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      const checkoutId = payload.id;
      const previousCheckoutStatus =
        payload.previous_attributes.checkout_status;
      const currentCheckoutStatus = payload.checkout_status;

      if (
        previousCheckoutStatus !== "abandoned" &&
        currentCheckoutStatus === "abandoned"
      ) {
        console.log(`--- Abandoned cart ${checkoutId} ---`);
      }
    },
  },

  CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
    },
  },
  CUSTOMERS_REDACT: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
    },
  },
  SHOP_REDACT: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: this is gdpr.js file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).